# Redshift UDF - Returning JSON keys

Tags: python, json, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a Redshift UDF with Python to return the keys of an JSON object:

```
create or replace function json_keys (j varchar(max))
    returns varchar(max)
    stable as $$
      import json
      arr = json.loads(j)
      for key in arr.keys():
      return str(key)
    $$ language plpythonu;
```

However when testing the function it only returns the last key in the object key i.e.

```
select json_keys('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2","key3": "value3"}') -- returns key3 only
```

What do I need to change to get it to return key1, key2 and key3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop returns the last item. checkout this.

```
create or replace function json_keys (j varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
stable as $$
    import json
    arr = json.loads(j)
    return '' if not arr else   ','.join(arr.keys())
$$ language plpythonu;

select json_keys('{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2","key3": "value3"}')
```

Comment: This works, thanks @kadalamittai! Interestingly it returns the keys in reverse order by default. What would be the best way to sort the array in order of appearance? I would have thought I could do `arr = sorted(arr)` after declaring arr but this fails to compile.

Comment: you have to do sorted(arr.keys())